# In appgyver, How to change app build target to 8.0 (Android)?

Tags: android, appgyver

In August 1, Google Play requires new apps to target at least Android 8.0 (API level 26). But in appgyver, I notice the latest available version is 4.5.3. Is there any way to upgrade it? Thanks!

[image: This is the screenshot of appgyver build options]

Comment: There is no Android version 4.5.3 so that number means something else

Comment: @tyczj Thanks! You are right. I will try to find a configuration file to change target level. It is kind of inconvenient in a hybrid app.

Answer (score 0):

I having the same issue, which is the maximum API level which appgyver supports is 21 only. GooglePlay required at least API Level 26 on August 2018 onward.

Answer (score 0):

AppGyver just officially answered this question [here](https://github.com/AppGyver/steroids/issues/1141#issuecomment-433885789).

**TL;TR** AppGyver is using Crosswalk, an Intel product, to build Android apps, and Intel has shut down Crosswalk over a year ago, now it is not possible for AppGyver to update their Build Service without rewriting the entier Android part, which would cost them too much, Supersonic and Steroids being depreciated, Android is officially abandonned by AppGyver, the Build Service will stay as is for apps that are internally distributed but won't allow to build apps destinated for Play Store.

---

**Edit: I found a solution that allow me to get the app accepted on the Play Store, but app will crash on Android 8.**

I then tested to install my app from the Play Store on a Android 6 with success but as we could expect it crashes on Android 8, the edited Target SDK number dupes the Play Store so it lets the APK in, but in the end it hasn't been built with Android 8 capabilities, so it won't work on that version.

All I had to do was to import my APK in **APK Icon Editor**, go in the **Properties** tab, change the **Target SDK** value to 26 (be sure to keep a lower value in the **Minimum SDK** field as it's the one telling what Android version can actually instal your app, if it's high then older phones won't have access to your app), and click on **Pack APK** to generate a new signed APK that is accepted by the Play Store!

Its as easy as this:

[image: How to edit APK Target SDK using APK Icon Editor]

I then tested to install my app from the Play Store on a Android 6 with success but as we could expect it crashes on Android 8, the edited Target SDK number dupes the Play Store so it lets the APK in, but in the end it hasn't been built with Android 8 capabilities, so it won't work on that version.

Edit: it seems like it also crashes on Android 7 :(

Answer (score 0):

Appgyver is constantly working on their platform and bringing latest updates. hopefully soon this issue will be resolved as well.. try contacting their support